# how to to bind check box in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have grid view and i binds up this check box like this :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_UserOFC1" runat="server" ToolTip="User of Easy Office" Checked='<%#Eval("UserOFC")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

how ever this field was nullable bit so run time error occurs :

```
Specified cast is not valid. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error: 


Line 1230:                    </HeaderTemplate>
Line 1231:                    <ItemTemplate>
Line 1232:                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_UserOFC1" runat="server" ToolTip="User of Easy Office" Checked='<%#Bind("UserOFC")%>'/>
Line 1233:                    </ItemTemplate>
Line 1234:                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headinglist_bg" HorizontalAlign="Left" />


Source File: f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx    Line: 1232
```

**---------------------------Updated------------------------------------**

```
 public void FillGrid(string GroupByText, string ColumnName, string SearchText)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var query = (dynamic)null;
            switch (GroupByText)
            {
                case "Customer":
                    query = db.Parties.Where(p => p.type_id.Equals("1")).OrderByDescending(p => p.Register_Date).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        type_id = p.type_id,
                        Ownername = p.Ownername,
                        Ownermob = p.Ownermob,
                        ContactPerson = p.ContactPerson,
                        ContactPersonmob = p.ContactPersonmob,
                        Phone = p.Phone,
                        Mobile = p.Mobile,
                        Room = p.Room,
                        Build = p.Build,
                        Road = p.Road,
                        Area = p.Area,
                        City = p.City,
                        country_id = p.country_id,
                        state_id = p.state_id,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        Remark = p.Remark,
                        UserOFC = p.UserOFC,
                        UserVAT = p.UserVAT,
                        UserINV = p.UserINV,
                        UserNone = p.UserNone,
                        Username = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.Ref_no).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Register_Date = p.Register_Date
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Enquiry":
                    query = db.Parties.Where(p => p.type_id.Equals("2")).OrderByDescending(p => p.Register_Date).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        type_id = p.type_id,
                        Ownername = p.Ownername,
                        Ownermob = p.Ownermob,
                        ContactPerson = p.ContactPerson,
                        ContactPersonmob = p.ContactPersonmob,
                        Phone = p.Phone,
                        Mobile = p.Mobile,
                        Room = p.Room,
                        Build = p.Build,
                        Road = p.Road,
                        Area = p.Area,
                        City = p.City,
                        country_id = p.country_id,
                        state_id = p.state_id,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        Remark = p.Remark,
                        UserOFC = p.UserOFC,
                        UserVAT = p.UserVAT,
                        UserINV = p.UserINV,
                        UserNone = p.UserNone,
                        Username = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.Ref_no).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Register_Date = p.Register_Date
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    query = db.Parties.OrderByDescending(p => p.Register_Date).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        type_id = p.type_id,
                        Ownername = p.Ownername,
                        Ownermob = p.Ownermob,
                        ContactPerson = p.ContactPerson,
                        ContactPersonmob = p.ContactPersonmob,
                        Phone = p.Phone,
                        Mobile = p.Mobile,
                        Room = p.Room,
                        Build = p.Build,
                        Road = p.Road,
                        Area = p.Area,
                        City = p.City,
                        country_id = p.country_id,
                        state_id = p.state_id,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        Remark = p.Remark,
                        UserOFC = p.UserOFC,
                        UserVAT = p.UserVAT,
                        UserINV = p.UserINV,
                        UserNone = p.UserNone,
                        Username = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.Ref_no).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Register_Date = p.Register_Date
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
                    break;
            }
            int count = 0;
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("type_id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ownername", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ownermob", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ContactPerson", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ContactPersonmob", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Phone", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Mobile", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Room", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Build", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Road", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Area", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("country_id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("state_id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Remark", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserOFC", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserVAT", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserINV", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserNone", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Username", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Register_Date", typeof(DateTime)));
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    count++;
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Id"] = int.Parse(item.Id.ToString());
                    dr["Name"] = item.Name.ToString();
                    dr["type_id"] = int.Parse(item.type_id.ToString());
                    if (item.Ownername != null)
                    {
                        dr["Ownername"] = item.Ownername.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Ownermob != null)
                    {
                        dr["Ownermob"] = item.Ownermob.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.ContactPerson != null)
                    {
                        dr["ContactPerson"] = item.ContactPerson.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.ContactPersonmob != null)
                    {
                        dr["ContactPersonmob"] = item.ContactPersonmob.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Phone != null)
                    {
                        dr["Phone"] = item.Phone.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Mobile != null)
                    {
                        dr["Mobile"] = item.Mobile.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Room != null)
                    {
                        dr["Room"] = item.Room.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Build != null)
                    {
                        dr["Build"] = item.Ownermob.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Road != null)
                    {
                        dr["Road"] = item.Road.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Area != null)
                    {
                        dr["Area"] = item.Area.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.City != null)
                    {
                        dr["City"] = item.City.ToString();
                    }
                    if(item.country_id!=null)
                    {
                        dr["country_id"] = int.Parse(item.country_id.ToString());
                    }
                    if (item.state_id != null)
                    {
                        dr["state_id"] = int.Parse(item.state_id.ToString());
                    }
                    if (item.Phone != null)
                    {
                        dr["Phone"] = item.Phone.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Mobile != null)
                    {
                        dr["Mobile"] = item.Mobile.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Email != null)
                    {
                        dr["Email"] = item.Email.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.Remark != null)
                    {
                        dr["Remark"] = item.Remark.ToString();
                    }
                    if(item.UserOFC!=null)
                    {
                        dr["UserOFC"] = bool.Parse(item.UserOFC.ToString());
                    }
                    if(item.UserVAT!=null)
                    {
                        dr["UserVAT"] = bool.Parse(item.UserVAT.ToString());
                    }
                    if(item.UserINV!=null)
                    {
                        dr["UserINV"] = bool.Parse(item.UserINV.ToString());
                    }
                    if(item.UserNone!=null)
                    {
                        dr["UserNone"] = bool.Parse(item.UserNone.ToString());
                    }
                    dr["Username"] = item.Username.ToString();
                    dr["Register_Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Register_Date.ToString());
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                DataView myDataView = new DataView();
                myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                if (this.ViewState["SortExp"] != null)
                {
                    myDataView.Sort = this.ViewState["SortExp"].ToString()
                             + " " + this.ViewState["SortOrder"].ToString();
                }
                GV_ViewCustomers.DataSource = myDataView;
            }
            else
            {
                myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(myDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow());
                GV_ViewCustomers.DataSource = myDataSet;
                GV_ViewCustomers.DataBind();
                int columncount = GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
                GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
            }
            GV_ViewCustomers.DataBind();
            if (GV_ViewCustomers.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                SetPageNumbers();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my grid view bind code.

Comment: `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBolean(Eval("UserOFC").ToString()) %>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `UserOFC` always contains either `True` or `False` then you can use the following approaach,

`Checked='<%# Convert.ToBolean(Eval("UserOFC").ToString()) %>'`

**OR**

If `UserOFC` may contain other that `True` or `False` (a `null` value) then you can use the following approach,

On `RowDataBound` even of the `GridView` use

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
   if(rowView["UserOFC"] != null)
   {
      try
      {
        (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserOFC1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBolean(rowView["UserOFC"].ToString());
      }
      catch
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this gives Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.DataItem' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: may be it's use like if (e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserOFC") != null)

Comment: @ShalinGajjar I updated my answer. It should be `e.Row.DataItem["UserOFC"]`

Comment: again it's give Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @ShalinGajjar I updated my answer. Check if it can be typecasted to `DataRowView`

Comment: ok.it's not getting compile time error but i got run time error from here Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: from starting with this line which we discuss it.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Ok. I suspect you are not checking for `RowType`. I updated with that code.

Comment: ok. it's works but still i'm getting error from grid view String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. i think i need to nullable checking at checkbox binding

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Hit a breakpoint and check what value you are getting at `rowView["UserOFC"]`. Based on that you can alter the condition what to check when binding the `CheckBox`.

Comment: my debug cursor no goes inside this block because i have no records in grid view.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Then how did you got the error? " String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Don't use `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("UserOFC").ToString()) %>'`

Comment: i think u tell me remove from this line from designer side.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar If `UserOFC` is always contains either "True" or "False" then you can use the first method. **Or** if `UserOFC` contains `null` then you can use second method. No need of using both.

Comment: which was second method

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Second method is in my answer after **OR**, which is from the `C#` code. First method is to do it from markup.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar That second answer is same as my first method. Which is from my comment.

Answer (score 2):

try setting the checked property of checkbox to

```
Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("UserOFC").ToString()) %>'
```